# Dynamic SUM based on NEW.id inside a trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Now I am writing an application that has PostgreSQL DB.
My task is to write trigger that will execute SQL statement, based on `new.id`.

There is only one problem, that trigger doesn't execute query. It's just insert nothing.

[DB output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0uqm.png)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bill_creator()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $build_bill$
declare
   summ   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(ITEMS.PRICE) INTO summ
   FROM ITEMS
   INNER JOIN PARTS
     ON PARTS.ITEM_ID = ITEMS.ID AND PARTS.ORDER_ID = NEW.ID;

    INSERT INTO BILLS (
        created,
        summary,
        cashier_id,
        customer_id,
        order_id,
        created_at,
        updated_at,
        options
    ) 
    VALUES (
        current_date,
        summ,
        1,
        new.customer_id,
        new_id,
        current_timestamp,
        current_timestamp,
        'None'
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$build_bill$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER build_bill AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE bill_creator();
```

I'm using Rails, so tables were created by ActiveRecords but they are stored in schema.

```
create_table "bills", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created"
  t.string   "options"
  t.integer  "summary"
  t.integer  "cashier_id"
  t.integer  "customer_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.integer  "order_id"
end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "customer_id"
  t.integer  "waiter_id"
  t.integer  "manager_id"
  t.integer  "chef_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "parts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "order_id"
  t.integer  "item_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "price"
  t.string   "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.integer  "menu_id"
end

add_index "parts", ["item_id"], name: "index_parts_on_item_id", using: :btree
add_index "parts", ["order_id"], name: "index_parts_on_order_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: Please show the `create trigger` statement and the `create table`for all tables involved.

Comment: Please replace the link with your actual "DB output" in text format. An external link is no good for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function looks basically good. I simplified and fixed some issues:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bill_creator()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$build_bill$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO bills (
     created,
     summary,
     cashier_id,
     customer_id,
     order_id,
     created_at,
     updated_at,
     options
   ) 
   SELECT
     current_date,
     SUM(i.price)
     1,
     NEW.customer_id,
     NEW.id              -- ! 'new_id was undefined !
     current_timestamp,
     current_timestamp,
     'None'
   FROM   parts p
   JOIN   items i ON p.item_id = i.id
   WHERE  p.order_id = NEW.id;

   RETURN NULL;
END
$build_bill$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You don't need the separate SELECT and variable assignment. Integrate it into a single `INSERT`, that's faster. Result is the same, the aggregate function `sum()` always returns a row, even if nothing is found.

`new_id` was undefined, I assume you meant `NEW.id`?

I use `RETURN NULL` because, [per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> The return value of a row-level trigger fired `AFTER` [...] is always ignored; it might as well be null.

Not sure why you have `created` and `created_at`. Both are type defined AS `t.datetime`, which should translate to Postgres `timestamp`. Also not sure why you write `current_date` instead of `current_timestamp` to the first.

**However**, it's not surprising that your inserted `summary` is NULL. Immediately after inserting a row in `orders`, there cannot be related entries in `parts`, yet - assuming referential integrity. So the idea of inserting a sum into `bill` at this point is **bound to fail**. You would have to `UPDATE` that column with every new `part` that's inserted / updated / deleted. It's a bag of fleas you'll have to deal with to keep that sum current - more or less ...

I suggest you **drop the column `bill.summary`** completely, and use a `VIEW` instead that calculates the sum dynamically. Can be a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to avoid repeated aggregation.